# What's the difference between 987 and (987) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I wrote a simple extension method.

```
Number.prototype.toMillion = function(){
 if(!Number.isNaN){
   return this/1000000;
 }
}
```

`987654321.toMillion()` raises:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

But `(987654321).toMillion()` works.

So my question is: what's the difference between `987` and `(987)`?

Just FYI:

```
typeof(987) => returns "number"
```

And

```
typeof((987)) still returns "number"
```

Comment: Whya are you checking `Number.isNaN`? Do you mean `this.isNaN()`?

Comment: In addition to the below answers, check out: `987654321..toMillion()`

Comment: @David - It would just be `isNaN(this)` (it's a global function, not a property of `Number.prototype`).

Comment: @JamesAllardice right, it’s still very wrong in the post. `Number.isNaN` will never be truey unless the OP attached a static method to `Number`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How would the parser know that the part following the `.` character is meant to signify a method call instead of another part of the number? For example:

```
10.1 // This is a number with a floating point
10.toMillion() //How does it know that this shouldn't be part of the number?
```

For that reason, you can't call methods on numeric literals. By placing the literal in parentheses (the [grouping operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.6)), the runtime will evaluate the contained expression and apply the method to the result of that evaluation.

The grouping operator removes the ambiguity of the `.` character.

---

**Update**

Following some thought and some investigation through the spec, there is a good reason to not allow the use of a lookahead to determine whether what follows the `.` character is part of the number or a property identifier.

As @CygnusX1 mentioned in the comments, you would have though that the two situations (`.` followed by a digit and `.` followed by a non-numeric character) could be differentiated by the use of a lookahead. Since identifiers can't start with a number, if a numeric character follows the `.`, it has to be a number. If a non-numeric character follows the `.`, it can't be part of the number. But that's not quite right.

There is one situation in which a non-numeric character can follow the `.` character but still be part of the number:

```
console.log(1.e5); // Logs '100000'
```

The `e` indicates that what follows is the *exponent*, and it can be either lowercase or uppercase. For this reason, using a lookahead would have to take into account that if the character following the `.` is `e` or `E`, it could still represent either a method or part of the number. It's easier to just disallow the use of properties on numeric literals.

Comment: The parser could decide it by having a look-ahead. If the element after dot is an identifier, then dot should not be a part of the number. However, as per Torsten Walter's example - since members can be numbers themselves, this is no longer possible.

Comment: @CygnusX1 - Torsten's second example is a syntax error. You can't define numeric properties like that (since identifiers cannot begin with a number).

Comment: In that case - a look-ahead lexer/parser should be able to deduct what the dot means.

Comment: thanks , so there is no way to define a method just invoke by 1.toMillion ?

Comment: @CygnusX1 - You would have thought so, but the [grammar](http://es5.github.com/#A.1) doesn't specify the use of a lookahead. Not sure why (there may be a perfectly logical reason, but my knowledge of syntactical grammars and parsers is limited).

Comment: @dfang - Correct. Just as there is no way to do it with any built-in methods of `Number`. For example, `123.toFixed(2)` is a syntax error.

Comment: @CygnusX1 - See my edit. There's a good reason a lookahead isn't used.

Comment: @CygnusX1 - I never realised until reading the spec to update this answer that you could do `1.e5` instead of just `1e5`. That's what threw me off when I originally answered (like you, I was wondering why a lookahead couldn't be used here).

Answer (score 5):

The `.` is overloaded in JavaScript.

```
123.123         // the interpreter assumes this is a floating point number
(123).123       // throws a syntax error, since an identifier
                // can't start with a number. - thanks James for pointing that out
(123).toMillion // refers to the function of the object returned by
                // the statement in braces
123.toMillion   // will throw a syntax error because a floating point number has only digits
```

Comment: Note that your second example actually throws a syntax error, since an identifier can't start with a number.

Answer (score 1):

When `987654321.toMillion()` is parsed "period" is interpreted as a delimiter of the fraction.  So if you want to use number as an object you need to wrap it with braces.